# LWJGL keyBinding for functions

Tags: java, swing, keyboard, lwjgl, key-bindings

I want to have keybinding, and make my game more dynamic, giving the user ability to change what each key on the keyboard does.

for example, I have the following :

```
public void jump(){...}
public void teleport(){...}
public void attack(){...}
```

now, after having these three functions, how do I map each of them to different keys? I am using

```
import org.lwjgl.input.Keyboard;
```

for my keyboard implementation. I tried following a tutorial online, i am not sure if I'm allowed to link it though... In the tutorial, it seems to be mainly for swing? how would I go on implementing it to LWJGL?

Comment: I'm not sure that lwjgl is all the compatiable with Swing as they use different rendering algorithms.  Having said that, if you want to use keyboard input with lwjgl, then you HAVE to use the lwjgl libraries to do it...

Comment: @MadProgrammer So how do i go about adding key-bindings...? I couldn't find anything on google that doesn't include swing....

Comment: Something like [LWJGL Basics 2 (Input)](http://wiki.lwjgl.org/index.php?title=LWJGL_Basics_2_(Input)) or [LWJGL Input](http://thecodinguniverse.com/lwjgl-input/)?  Try using "LWJGL keyboard" or "LWJGL input" as search words..

Comment: @MadProgrammer but this does not achieve what i wanted... which is calling a function upon the click, which is dynamic. i want the function to be binded to the key itself, to the key the player chooses it to be binded to

Comment: Tough, that's the way the API works.  Assign the virtual key variable to a value (for instance `up = ?`) when the corresponding key event occurs which matches the value of `up`, call your method.  Key bindings work in a simular way, they just do all the dirty work for you